# sharing folders with passwords

Tags: linux, shared-folders

I have a Linux box which should share a few directories to other systems over the LAN.
The other systems are running linux as well.

I'd like to associate a different password for each folder without creating different users. Is there a way to achieve that?

Feel free to put NFS and SSH combos into the mix. The key point is that I need different passwords for different directories, like this:

EXPORTED DIR: /opt/dir1       PASSWORD:   'foo'

EXPORTED DIR: /usr/lib/dir2   PASSWORD:   'bar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to password protect each folder then you'll have to use something like Samba.  There is no other method of sharing a file system/directory I know of that'll allow you to put a (shared) password on a share.

Answer (score 1):

If the folders are small in size perhaps encrypt each with a different password using [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/).